# ReferenceError: players is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Everything was working fine, but I just loaded the file and it not working for no reason.
and I'm getting this error

```
  /home/Ales/latinbot2/Commands/estado.js:54
              .addField('**Jugadores en linea:**', `${players || "0"}`)
                                                      ^
    ReferenceError: players is not defined
        at Command.run (/home/Ales/latinbot2/Commands/estado.js:54:51)
        at Event.run (/home/Ales/latinbot2/Events/interactionCreate.js:44:13)
        at Client.<anonymous> (/home/Ales/latinbot2/Structures/Client.js:109:49)
        at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
        at InteractionCreateAction.handle (/home/Ales/latinbot2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/InteractionCreate.js:83:12)
        at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (/home/Ales/latinbot2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
        at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/Ales/latinbot2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:346:31)
        at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/Ales/latinbot2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:493:22)
        at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/Ales/latinbot2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:327:10)
        at callListener (/home/Ales/latinbot2/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:290:14)
```

```
    const fs = require("fs");
    
    const Discord = require("discord.js");
    const yaml = require("js-yaml");
    
    const supportbot = yaml.load(
      fs.readFileSync("./Configs/supportbot.yml", "utf8")
    );
    const cmdconfig = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync("./Configs/commands.yml", "utf8"));
    
    const Command = require("../Structures/Command.js");
    const { timeStamp } = require("console");
    var request = require('request');
    
    const Gamedig = require('gamedig');
    const cooldown={}
    
    let state = null;
    
    
    setInterval(() => {
    
    
      Gamedig.query({
        type: 'minecraft',
        host: 'mc.latinplay.net',
        port: '25565'
      })
      .then((updatedState) => {
        state = updatedState;
        players = state.players.length;
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("El servidor esta offline.");
    });
    }, 6000);
    
    module.exports = new Command({
      name: cmdconfig.EstadoCommand,
      description: cmdconfig.EstadoCommandDesc,
      async run(interaction) {
    
          
          if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.find(e=>e.name=="〘〙【 Staff Superior 】〘〙") && interaction.user.id in cooldown && cooldown[interaction.user.id] - Date.now() > 0) // in cool down
              return interaction.reply("✨ **Este comando esta en cooldown! Espera 5 minutos para volver a usarlo.**");
          cooldown[interaction.user.id] = Date.now() + 300000; // 5 min in ms.
          
          const LatinEstado = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setColor('RANDOM')
              .setTitle('  **Estado del Servidor**')
              .setURL("https://store.latinplay.net/")
              .addField('**Jugadores en linea:**', `${players || "0"}`)
              .addField('**Estado Actual:**', "**En Linea**", true)
              .setThumbnail('https://media0.giphy.com/media/5RQ6coK6GVXGfPPq69/giphy.gif?cid=790b76115867f0dba05d9cf2aceb80efed5b0e494387e3b2&rid=giphy.gif&ct=g')
              .setFooter({
                  text: 'LatinBot | Version 1.0 ',
                  iconURL: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/953043417234026547/988805760458821642/Diseno_sin_titulo.png'
              });
          interaction.reply({
              embeds: [LatinEstado],
          });
    
      }
    });
```

Comment: In that scope, is ```players``` defined?

Answer (score -1):

You're defining `players` inside the `then` of `setInterval`. This makes `players` local to that function, and it's not accessible outside of it, so when try to use `players` in the `run` method of `Command` object, js can't find a variable named `players`, and got the error.

Therefore, you need to declare `players` in a scope that's accessible to both the `setInterval` and the `run` method.

```
let players = 0; // Declare players at the top of your module

setInterval(() => {
 Gamedig.query({
   type: 'minecraft',
   host: 'mc.latinplay.net',
   port: '25565'
 })
 .then((updatedState) => {
   state = updatedState;
   players = state.players.length; // Update players inside the setInterval function
 }).catch((error) => {
   console.log("El servidor esta offline.");
 });
}, 6000);

module.exports = new Command({
 // ...
 async run(interaction) {
   // ...
   .addField('**Jugadores en linea:**', `${players || "0"}`) // Now players is accessible here
   // ...
 }
});
```

Comment: it does not works, its say 0 on the player side when i execute the command.

Comment: Are you sure that the ```Gamedig.query``` function is returning the correct data? Could you please check if the ```state``` object contains the ```players``` property and if it's an array?